# Removing specific character does not work

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to get rid of some characters from:

```
list(structure(list(X1 = c("Station Name: Roches_Point", "Station Height: 40 M", 
"Latitude:51.789", "Longitude: -8.240")), .Names = "X1", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), structure(list(
    X1 = c("Station Name: Newport", "Station Height: 22 M", "Latitude:53.920", 
    "Longitude: -9.570")), .Names = "X1", row.names = c(NA, -4L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")))
```

This function does what I want, but I can't remove letter M in station height.

```
metadata_list <- lapply(metadata_list, function(x) 
  sapply(x, function(y){
    str_replace(y,"Station Name: |Station Height: | M|Latitude:|Longitude: ", "" )
  }))
```

If I run it again only with this expression it works:

```
metadata_list <- lapply(metadata_list, function(x) 
  sapply(x, function(y){
    str_replace(y," M", "" )
  }))
```

Just curious what is the reason?

Comment: Use `str_replace_all` instead of `str_replace`.

Comment: Thanks! Although I dont see how is this exactly same as those questions you have linked!? It is the same topic...

Comment: The duplicate reasons are all valid, see [demo](https://ideone.com/TtVpro).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the pattern you are supplying will match with `"Station Height: "` for that string, and replace once and stop there.. You should use `str_replace_all` which will replace all matches in each string. With just a small change:

```
metadata_list <- lapply(metadata_list, function(x) 
  sapply(x, function(y){
    str_replace_all(y,"Station Name: |Station Height: | M|Latitude:|Longitude: ", "" )
  }))
print(metadata_list)
[[1]]
     X1            
[1,] "Roches_Point"
[2,] "40"          
[3,] "51.789"      
[4,] "-8.240"      

[[2]]
     X1       
[1,] "Newport"
[2,] "22"     
[3,] "53.920" 
[4,] "-9.570"
```

Comment: Thanks - what is the difference?

Comment: @m_c With `str_replace_all` or `gsub`.

Comment: @m_c Just a swap of `str_replace` for `str_replace_all`

Comment: I got that :) , I am asking for explanation.

Comment: Compare `str_view("Station Height: 22 M", "Station Height: | M")` and `str_view_all("Station Height: 22 M", "Station Height: | M")`. Normally a regular expression will match the first piece of the string that it can, even if others match. `str_view_all` and `str_replace_all` show and replace, respectively, all matches in the string, not just the first one. In your case, in the string `"Station Height: 22 M"`, because the first part was matched and replaced the second `M` was never replaced